# AWS EBS: crashed root volume recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I was in situation where I was in need to enlarge EBS volume size, so I did it via AWS Console -> changing from default 8GB to 15GB.

Then I followed this tutorial: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-resize-ext4-root-partition-live-without-umount

Next, AWS Console -> EC2 instance -> reboot.

Then, after few minutes some errors occured: `1/2 checks passed: These checks monitor your software and network configuration for this instance.`.

---

So I decided to create a snapshot of this volume and create a completely fresh EC2 instance with additional volume with this snapshot.

I tried to make this in this way: https://devopscube.com/mount-ebs-volume-ec2-instance/

But after `sudo file -s /dev/xvdf` I see error with information this is a root EBS volume, so I can't make it.

---

That was my last logs of instance after "Reboot" action:

```
[[0;32m OK [0m Unmounted /run/user/1000.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped target Swap.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
Stopping Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors…ng dmeventd or progress polling...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Shutdown.
[[0;32m OK [0m Reached target Final Step.
Starting Reboot...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors,…sing dmeventd or progress polling.
Stopping LVM2 metadata daemon...
[[0;32m OK [0m Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon.
http://8432758.683718 reboot: Restarting system
```

---

Any ideas guys how to restore and get files from this volume?

Comment: Do you have a snapshot from before you started changing your EBS volume? When you say you "see error with information", can you edit your question to include details of the error?

Comment: Nope... and that was my big mistake, I've just added last instance logs.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give precise error messages regarding where you say "I see error with information this is a root EBS volume".